# Access sesssion variable on HTML template PHP

Tags: php, html, front-controller

I have a simple web form where I want the form to remember the last entry in case the validation is retrieving an error.

The general process is:

enter data in the form `-- press submit -- data validation --` if error, display error message, keep entered data on the form & do not store in `DB | if no error --` store in DB.

I am currently using HTML template rendering and would like to keep doing so.

The form is plain HTML and the form part looks like this

```
 <table class="form-table" id="addContact">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Eesnimi:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="firstName" placeholder="Sinu eesnimi.." value= "{{ session.firstName }}"></td>
        </tr>
```

I have currently stored the values as Session Variables. The session is started from Index.php and the validation and HTML template rendering happens on `Index.php`. The form is held on Add.html

`Index.php`
`add.html`

`Session` variables as held as follows:

```
$_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;
    $_SESSION['lastName'] = $lastName;
    $_SESSION['phones'] = $phones;
```

Currently, the form is just displaying the `{{ session.firstName }}` and not the session variable value. I tried setting the variable in the HTML template, but this caused a general error.

```
<?php

namespace {

    use tpl\Scope;

    function render_template($templatePath, $data = []) {
        $node = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $node->loadHTMLFile($templatePath);

        tpl\traverse($node, new Scope($data));

        return $node->saveHTML();
    }

}

class Entry {
        public $key;
        public $value;

        public function __construct($name, $key) {
            $this->key = $name;
            $this->value = $key;
        }

        public function __toString() {
            return $this->key . "->" . $this->value;
        }
    }
```

And calling the render_template(template path, data-here pushing $_SESSION)

Comment: What type of templating are you using? Laravel with Blade? Have you tried {!! session.firstName !!} or {{ $_SESSION['firstName'] }} with any luck?

Comment: you should include the tag of your templating engine as this is what the whole problem is about.

Comment: As far as i can understand, you are using some `{{ --- }}` blade kinda code in .HTML file ?
It will never work.
Templates should have `.blade.php` or atleast `.php`. as extension in order to be interpreted for PHP syntax.

Comment: I am using tpl.php to generate the .html file. Updated the initial description.